# Propiedad style en objeto javascript con selectElementByClassName

Tags: javascript

estoy iniciandome en javascript y seguro que mi duda es una tonteria pero no consigo solventarla:

Cuando selecciono un objeto del dom con document.getElementByClassName despues no puedo acceder a su propiedad style:

```
    // no funciona
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName("class-name");
    element[0].style.width = "100%;"
```

En cambio cuando lo hago usando getElementById si:

```
    //correcto
    var element = document.getElementsById("id_name");
    element.style.width = "100%;"
```

Gracias de antemano.
Un saludo!

Comment: Trata de mostrar tu html también para poder ayudarte.

Comment: El problema es que el estilo que intentas aplicar no es perceptible, prueba con esto y verás que funciona: **`element[0].style.color = "red"`**, OJO, no uses `;`

Comment: No sé, la verdad yo te recomiendo que uses querySelector, es más fácil y es menos código.
document.querySelector('.class-name').style.width = '100%';

Comment: Tienes un error: getElementsById debería ser getElementById

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el estilo que intentas aplicar no es perceptible, si pruebas a cambiarle el color, verás que funciona. **Nótese** que si usas el punto y coma al final no funciona.

```js
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("class-name");
element[0].style.color = "red"

var element1 = document.getElementById("id_name");
element1.style.color = "green"
```

```html
<div class="class-name">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p id="id_name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

### Otra posibilidad

En los navegadores modernos la selección se hace mucho más simple mediante el uso de [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) o [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorall).

Esto te permite seleccionar un elemento en particular o un grupo de elementos. Y permite selecciones complejas, basadas en combinaciones como la clase, el tipo de elemento, el id, la posición, etc...

El único problema es que no funciona en navegadores antiguos (ver [tabla de compatibilidad](https://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector) según navegadores).

Aquí te dejo un pequeño ejemplo para abrir el apetito:

```js
var element = document.querySelector(".class-name");
element.style.color = "red";

var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".class-name");
elements[1].style.color="blue" ;
```

```html
<div class="class-name">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p id="id_name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>

<div class="class-name">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!, solo una última cosa: A que te refieres con propiedad no perceptible?

Comment: @MarcosLC me refiero a que aplicar `width: 100%` no es perceptible en algunos casos, se aumenta el ancho al 100% pero si tienes un contenido corto no se apreciará o si no tienes un color de fondo que haga contraste. Para probar estilos vete a algo más perceptible, como cambiar el color. A eso me refería.